Not able to send localized push notification from Azure Notification Hub after migrating to FCMv1 from FCM Legacy API
I am updating my production service to use FCMv1 APIs instead of FCM legacy as they have been terminated by ANH. After updating I am sending test notification from azure portal from Notification Hub -> Test Send. I am able to send normal payload like below to mobile apps and which gets delivered successfully.
{
  "message": {
    "notification": {
        "title": "message title",
        "body": "message body"
    }
  }
}

But when I am sending localized notification payload in below format I am getting error on the portal that
the Notification payload is invalid.
{
  "notification": {
    "title_loc_key": "test_title",
    "title_loc_args": [
        "abcd title"
    ],
    "body_loc_key": "test_body",
    "body_loc_args": [
        "Test body text"
    ]
  }
}


This is the actual notification I was sending earlier in legacy API on production and was working fine. I need to send in this format only as to support multiple languages, template is stored in mobile. I just need to pass title and body args in the notification.
It is also not working when notification is pushed from code as well. I can't find any document which states if there is a different format for sending args in FCMv1. Please help me fix this issue.

This will resolve Notification payload is invalid issue.
The change is {"message": {"android": {.......}}
Example playload
{
  "message": {
    "android": {
      "notification": {
        "body_loc_args": [
          "string"
        ],
        "title_loc_args": [
          "string"
        ],
        "title_loc_key": "string",
        "body_loc_key": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}


Message format should be:
{"message": {
"notification": {
"title": "Weather Update",
"body": "Current weather conditions:\nTemperature: 25°C\nHumidity: 60%\nWind Speed: 10 km/h"
},
"android": {
"data": {
"temperature": "25°C",
"humidity": "60%",
"wind_speed": "10 km/h"
}
}
}
}
Reference: https://medium.com/@pramodyahk/migrating-to-fcm-v1-in-azure-notification-hubs-android-push-notifications-c342d76adfb2#:~:text=Please%20note%20the%20new%20notification%20body%20format%20below.

This notification payload is working fine. But I need to send localized notification payload.
